# Python - How to convert a MAC address into an IP address

Tags: python, networking

Let's say I have the MAC address `fe:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff`. Is there a function or series of functions that can convert that into its corresponding IP address?

Comment: Do you want to do that for local devices?

Comment: It's possible to have more than one IP address associated with a MAC address